# Ft232h doesn't run as a normal user , it requires root user

Tags: c, jtag

I'm using the ftdixx driver and ftdi.so file to communicate with ft232h module. FT_Open(iport, &fthandle) function doesn't work with normal user. If it is root user,it is working and opening the port .In normal user mode, it is failing with segmentation fault in FT_Open(iport, &fthandle) function. So what could be cause of this issue.

```
int main()
{
FT_STATUS ftstatus;
FT_HANDLE fthandle;
int iport =0;
DWORD libversion = 0;

ftstatus = FT_GetLibraryVersion(&libversion)
if(ftstatus != FT_OK)
{
}

ftstatus = FT_Open(iport, &fthandle)
if(ftstatus != FT_OK)
{
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Normal users don't have access to physical I/O ports on Linux, aside of programs with the corresponding capabilities

Comment: What operating system and what version of the ftdixx driver and ftdi.so library? I've never heard of the ftdixx driver and library files normally have a "lib" prefix in their name.

Comment: Linux operating system. Libftd2xx.so @IanAbbott

Comment: @Adalcar is there way to give access to the normal user ?

Comment: You need a UDEV rule to set the permissions. Assuming the FT232H is using the factory default USB vendor and product IDs and you want the device to be accessible to members of the "plugdev" group, the following rule in "/etc/udev/rules.d/99-libftdi.rules" will do: `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="0660"`.  (The "plugdev" group is common on Debian or Ubuntu systems, but I think Fedora uses the "uaccess" group instead of "plugdev", so the UDEV rule would need to be changed accordingly.) You also need to add your username to the group.

Comment: Regarding the cause of the segmentation fault within FT_Open, it is hard to tell because the source code for this function is not publicly available. There is an alternative, open source library "libftdi" with a different interface to FTDI's libftd2xx library, but is commonly packaged by Linux distros. It may be worth checking out. There is the old, "legacy" branch "libftdi-0.x" based on the libusb 0.x API, and the new branch "libftdi-1.x" based on the libusb 1.0 API.

Comment: it doesnt worked out for me . already I had tried changing the udev rule set @IanAbbott

Comment: why don't you use the termios.h standard unix interface?  It runs pleasantly with fdti serial interfaces, and doesn't need a library to interface.  And the program you write will be portable to any other unix platform, with minor or no modifications at al. `man termios`

Comment: Hey, @Vinooooo did you get an update on that? Were you able to fix the issue ?